# AWS namespace not recognized in Vsual Studio 2022 after installing AWS toolkit and AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue trying to use AWS in C# in Visual Studio 2022. This is for a unity project in v2021.3.15f1.  I've installed the AWS Toolkit (and logged into it) and used nuget to download AWSSDK.Core (3.7.105.8), AWSSDK.ApiGatewayV2 (3.7.100.79) and AWSSDk.DynamoDBv2 (3.7.101.50).

However, when I create an empty file and try typing 'using Amazon;' it doesn't recognize the namespace. Is there any step that I'd be missing?

I've tried restarting the application, reinstalling the SDKs, updating them

### In advance, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems there was an error with Visual studio because it was attached to a Unity project. I had to select my unity poject and let it recompile after which Visual Studio accepted the new sdks